# How to rerun a debugging version of an app on a device without reuploading from Android Studio?

Tags: android, android-studio

I am following the guide [Build your first app](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/firstapp/) at [developer.android.com](https://developer.android.com/) to get started with development. I am using a laptop with Ubuntu 18.04 and Android Studio 3.1.2 for development. At the end of the tutorial I clicked the `Run` button and I was able to upload and install the app on my device
 (Moto G, Android version 7) using an USB cable from my laptop. The app seems to run fine on my mobile device, but when I click the back button in the app it exits and I am not able to rerun the app (I cannot find any Icon for it on the home screen on my device).

Of course, I could upload it again from Android Studio, but I would like to keep it on the device, such that I can rerun it without being connected to Android Studio via the USB cable. What is the easiest way to achieve this?

Comment: This should be automatic, when ADB uploads the app into your device, it remains there. Which device are you using? If you don't see your app icon, try to search it inside your applications list in your launcher, commonly the central bottom button in your main screen.

Comment: Take a look here to find your applications list: https://ibb.co/cMTPmT

Comment: @MarcEstrada Thanks for the good help. I found the app in the application list as you suggested by typing the start of its name in the search field. I could then move the app from the result list to my home screen. And I think works fine now. I can rerun it by pressing its icon. Thanks for the support!

Comment: You're welcome :) Should I post the answer as an answer or it's not necessary?

Comment: Yes I think it would great if you posted your comment as a short answer!

Comment: Great! I've done it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should be automatic, when ADB uploads the app into your device, it remains there until you uninstall it manually. If you don't see your app icon (in the home screen), try to search it inside your applications list in your launcher, commonly the central bottom button in your main screen.

Take a look to this image to know better how to access to the apps list.

[image: Apps list]

In this screen should appear your app icon.